# Were there problems for "NASA’S ICON satellite"? Did PG&E shut off UC Berkeley's Space Sciences Laboratory's power?

Tags: nasa, earth-observation, mission-control, payload-deployment, ionospheric-connection-explorer

The San Jose Mercury News article [How PG&E’s power shutdown threatened a NASA mission](https://www.mercurynews.com/2019/10/12/how-pges-power-shutdown-threatened-a-nasa-mission/) describes a last minute rush to obtain extension cords, generators, and access to backup fuel when it was learned that a PG&E blackout of UC Berkeley's Space Sciences Laboratory might be scheduled during the launch and deployment of "NASA’S ICON satellite" ([Ionospheric Connection Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionospheric_Connection_Explorer)).

What exactly was the risk to the mission if the Berkeley lab had lost all power during the launch and deployment? Were they in a position to intervene if something had gone wrong, or were they the only station to record important telemetry that might be necessary, or in reality was there no risk to the mission?

**update 1:** and possibly helpful, WIRED's [UC Berkeley Was About to Launch a Satellite. Then PG&E Said It Was Cutting Power](https://www.wired.com/story/icon-launch-blackout/)

**update 2:** It's now past tense, so I've added *Were there any problems?* Basically let's get an answer that can be accepted.

---

[image: ICON launch, UC Berkeley's Space Sciences Laboratory]

> A mission control team monitors the launch of the ICON on Thursday evening from inside UC Berkeley's Space Sciences Laboratory. The satellite lifted off at Cape Canaveral Air Force Station in Florida. (Photo courtesy of Steven Beckwith of UC Berkeley)

Source: San Jose Mercury News' [How PG&E’s power shutdown threatened a NASA mission](https://www.mercurynews.com/2019/10/12/how-pges-power-shutdown-threatened-a-nasa-mission/)

Comment: I'm very curious to hear specific issues that they may have faced, personally. Hopefully someone informed chimes in. Just speaking overall from an IT standpoint - day to day we prepare to handle any unexpected power outage. That's not the same as a planned outage - if I know I'll be loosing power at some stage and still need to maintain operations - then I must find a suitable stand-in for the missing layer of redundancy. So the rush may have just been something on those lines - "If we'll be on generator already, we need more backup plans."

Comment: @Saiboogu my thinking is that if what they did was mission-critical it would definitely have had redundant power in place, so my guess is that the site wasn't mission-critical to begin with. Instead, I think that the linked articles are adding a bit of drama.